# Android UIautomator swiping ViewAnimator

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm testing my app but have a problem with the DatePicker.
All I need is to swipe down until another month appears (searching for a specific date).

[image: Screenshot]

The structure is a bit tricky but I made it work using

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ViewAnimator.class.getName())).scrollTextIntoView("November")
```

Problem is, even though the view is scrolling, it is

1) scrolling in the wrong direction (up)

2) not stopping even though a November has already passed.(even November 2017 or November 2015...)

How can I create this condition. After all the views are named in a unique way so checking the structure would be possible finding "01 November 2016".

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I found a solution that works more or less fine:

At first I tried to use the sub conditions since UiSelector might have a child definition. But that proved hard since inside of the ViewAnimator is a (single) child object ListView containing the "calendar month" view.
So finding a childview in there with the description "15 December..." was tricky.

The new solution does this.

1. while (tries < MAX_TRIES)
2. if element with description "15 December ..." exists 
   -> click and exit loop
3. scroll down 1 element (next month) 
   -> tries++

I repeat this until the element is found (and clicked) or the maximum scroll tries are exhausted.
After scrolling I let the device wait for 1 second. This is useful since swiping is called asynchronously and would continue swiping for a moment while processing the click.
This did not show as a problem (since the view is already clicked) but still might be confusing.

I hope this helps! Feel free to post a better solution if you find one.

```
int tries = 0;
while (tries < MAX_TRIES) {
   UiObject2 dateField = mDevice.findObject(
           By.descStartsWith(SEARCH_DATE));
       if (dateField != null) {
           dateField.click();
           break;
       } else {
           tries ++;
           new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().
                   className(android.widget.ViewAnimator.class.getName())).
                   scrollToEnd(1);
           mDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.descStartsWith(SEARCH_DATE)), 1000);
       }
}
```